# Telerik KendoUI Angular2 Grid- Page Size drop-down not updating displayed record items in Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to use Telerik's new KendoUI Angular 2 Grid control, and the drop-down that changes pageSize doesn't seem to update the size of the grid to display the amount of records selected. It changes the number of pages and the pageInfo (1-10 of 100 items), but not the grid itself. Am I doing something wrong? Following is the code snippet provided by Telerik on their site that also doesn't work in Plnkr. Thanks.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul class="configurator">
      <li>
        <label for="type">Type of the pager:
            <select id="type" [(ngModel)]="type">
                <option value="numeric">Numeric</option>
                <option value="input">Input</option>
            </select>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="buttonCount">Maximum number of buttons:
            <input id="buttonCount" class="k-textbox" type="number" [(ngModel)]="buttonCount"/>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="info"><input id="info" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="info">Show info</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="pageSizes" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="pageSizes">
        <label for="pageSizes">Show page sizes</label><br>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="previousNext" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="previousNext">
        <label for="previousNext">Show previous / next buttons</label><br>
      </li>
     </ul>

      <kendo-grid
          [data]="gridView"
          [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [skip]="skip"
          [pageable]="{
            buttonCount: buttonCount,
            info: info,
            type: type,
            pageSizes: pageSizes,
            previousNext: previousNext
          }"
          [scrollable]="'none'"
          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
        >
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private gridView: GridDataResult;

    private buttonCount: number =  5;
    private info: boolean = true;
    private type: 'numeric' | 'input' = 'numeric';
    private pageSizes: boolean = true;
    private previousNext: boolean = true;

    private pageSize: number = 5;
    private skip: number = 0;
    private products: any[] = Array(100).fill({}).map((x, idx) => ({
        "ProductID": idx,
        "ProductName": "Product" + idx,
        "Discontinued": idx % 2 === 0
    }));

    constructor() {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    protected pageChange({ skip }: PageChangeEvent): void {
        this.skip = skip;
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    protected sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    private loadProducts(): void {
        this.gridView = {
            data: this.products.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize),
            total: this.products.length
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, the pageSize should be updated inside the pageChange event handler, similar to the following:

```
protected pageChange({ skip, take }: PageChangeEvent): void {
    this.skip = skip;
    this.pageSize = take;
    this.loadProducts();
}
```

Comment: If I change pageSize from 10 to 100, it loads the 100 items. The grid of course increases its height. If I then go back to pageSize 10, the grid keeps the same height. I have 10 items and then blank space where previously were displayed the other 90 items, and then the pager. Is this expected or am I missing something?